# how to use sqlite in iOS when i use iPhone to run the project

Tags: ios, sqlite

when i use simulator,i can find the database file in /documents .but when i use my iPhone to run the project,i can not find the database file.
what time should i create the database file or use this code in my project?

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentFolderPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbFilePath = [documentFolderPath stringByAppendingString:DATABASENAME];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL isExist = [fm fileExistsAtPath:dbFilePath];
if (!isExist) {
    NSString *backupDbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingString:DATABASENAME];
    [fm copyItemAtPath:backupDbPath toPath:dbFilePath error:nil];
}
```

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826352/why-a-database-hasnt-created/24826701#24826701

Comment: it does not work.....what difference between simulator and iPhone when i  create a  database file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first time or the database file does not exist in the documents directory, you have to copy DB file to document directory:

```
-(void)copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory{
    // Check if the database file exists in the documents directory.
    NSString *destinationPath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]) {
        // The database file does not exist in the documents directory, so copy it from the main bundle now.
        NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
        NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];

        // Check if any error occurred during copying and display it.
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
```

Ref: http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the directories of iPhone or iPad. So even if you successfully created a database, you won't see it. You can judge its existence by read data from it.